# Google chrome conflict with oracle-xe's kernel parameters

Tags: linux, google-chrome, conflict, oracle-xe

I'm trying to install oracle-xe in my development machine (Linux maya) by following the guide from https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10280550&tstart=0#10280550.

After the step of modify and applying of the kernel parameters, the chrome can no longer render any page, including settings, history, ... I can confirm the chrome does download the web content normally by viewing the views from developer tools (element, scripts, networking, ...), but just can't display the contents, only a blank page.

Until I remove the config file for oracle-xe (/etc/sysctl.d/60-oracle.conf) and reboot my machine, the chrome works again.

I've try to google for the answer with no luck.

So, no one will install the oracle-xe in the development machine? or am I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem when installing Oracle 11.2.0.1 Server on a Ubuntu machine. The workaround for my problem was to reduce the size specified for the **kernel.shmmax** parameter in the *sysctl* config file. It's likely the suitable value for **shmmax** varies with the amount of physical memory on the machine; with 2GB of RAM, Chrome starting rendering pages again when the kernel parameter was set to 1GB.